# Cannot remove .panfs file from HPC

Tags: macos, unix, hpc

Hi I have some folders having .panfs.f70412ac. files

I tried remove those directories using following commands

```
rm -r <dir>
rm -rf <dir>
rm -Rf <dir>
```

anyone of above commands doesn't work for me. 
I tried to remove individual .panfs.f70412ac. files using rm command. It also unsuccessful

Does any one have an idea how to remove those directories. I have checked following question and it doesn't resolve my problem.

[Can't remove a directory in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947559/cant-remove-a-directory-in-unix)

I have Mac OS and this folders in High Performance Computer. Not in my computer.

Comment: What output do you get? Also, if it is a dir it needs `rmdir` instead, when it is empty of course.

Comment: Those files are locked or open by other filesystem clients. They will disappear once all clients have closed their file handles. It could also mean that something has stalled and some of the clients (or even the FS server(s)) have to be rebooted. Also, this is not a question about programming and is off-topic here..