# .jupyter cannot be deleted or written to

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, symlink

My jupyter notebook command stopped working, and I believe it is because my .jupyter directory is behaving strangely.
If I try to delete it, it neither errors or gets deleted.
For example, this works, but should not.

```sh
rm -rf .jupyter
cd .jupyter
```

If I then run,

```sh
touch hello.txt
```

I get `touch: hello.txt: Invalid argument`
Has anyone run into this and solved it?

#### More Info

I don't think it's a symlink:

```
(py36) ➜  ~ ls -halt .jupyter
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 389 shleifer staff 13K Jul  5 19:25 ../
drwxr-xr-x   10 shleifer staff 320 Dec 28  2019 ./
```

Comment: try `sudo rm -rf .jupyter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't remove a directory in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947559/cant-remove-a-directory-in-unix)

Comment: No, it is a much larger problem. I can succesfully delete the dir with that command, but other dirs that used to exit cannot be ls'd anymore!